Updating java version in Android studio
I migrated an existing android project to android studio ladybug. I am stuck with this error
Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 8.4. Cannot sync the project.

It seems to pick up Java 21.0.3 from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home. This is what I tried

Went to File -> New Project Setup -> Project Default Structure -> Gradle and updated Default Gradle JDK as /Users/ashwin/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.25-ms (this contains bin/java and has java 11). It accepts this as a valid jdk.
As mentioned here I set the environment variable STUDIO_JDK as /Users/ashwin/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.25-ms

But both/either of these don't seem to have any effect. I get the same error complaining of Java 21.0.3 incompatibility. What could be going on here and how can I fix this?
EDIT
build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.6.4'
        room_version = "2.6.1"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.3.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id("androidx.room") version "$room_version" apply false

}

Attaching project structure screenshots





Can you share your build.gradle file and your Project Structure settings?

You might want to consider updating Gradle instead.

@tomerpacific done

@Ashwin - Your application level build.gradle file is missing. Do you have a compatibility clause there for a specific Java version?

@tomerpacific in application level gradle I only have this "    compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}" (related to java)

Restart Android Studio after the changes, and restart the system as well, as sometimes it takes a system restart for Environment variables to take effect.
